# Relation Question for Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb Z$ and define a relation $\tau$ on the power set of $X$ as follows:

$\forall A,B\in\wp(X)[A\tau B\iff\text{the sum of the elements in }A\text{ equals the sum of the elements in }B]$.

a)Prove that $\tau$ is an equivalence relation.

b)Let $X = \{0,1,2,3\}$. Write down the partition of $\wp(X)$ given by the equivalence classes of $\tau$ for this set $X$.

I know that for part a) to prove its a equivalence relation i need to prove that both A&B are reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive. But i am not to sure how do i prove it specifically.
While for part b) of the question I totally don't understand at all. Thank you for teaching me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preassume that the sum of elements in $X$ is well defined and finite.

Define $s:\wp(X)\to\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ by stating that: $$s(A)=\sum_{a\in A}a$$

Then: $$A\tau B\iff s(A)=s(B)$$

So

- $\tau$ is reflexive $\iff\forall A\in\wp(X)[s(A)=s(A)]$ for all $A\in\wp(\mathcal Z)$
- $\tau$ is symmetric  $\iff\forall A,B\in\wp(X)[s(A)=s(B)\implies s(B)=s(A)]$
- $\tau$ is transitive $\iff\forall A,B,C\in\wp(X)[s(A)=s(B)\wedge s(B)=s(C)\implies s(A)=s(C)]$

Observe that it is very obvious now that $\tau$ is an equivalence relation.

The partition is: $$\{\{A\in\wp(X)\mid s(A)=k\}\mid k\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}\}$$This allows you to answer (b).

Comment: am i allowed to write like this for exam for proving equivalence? or do i need to add in explanation of own for proving? Thank you!

Comment: After introducing $A\tau B\iff s(A)=s(B)$ you can just say things like: "$A\tau A$ is true since evidently $s(A)=s(A)$. This for every $A\in\wp(X)$ so we conclude that $\tau$ is reflexive". And likewise for symmetric and transitive.

Comment: okay, i get what you mean. Really appreciate your help for guiding me to this question.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer really satisfies then you can accept it.